# How to make tkinter menu label run only the function attached to it?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python and learning to make some basic tkinter apps in windows.
I have defined a menubar and add one menu to it. Then added multiple labels to this menu, but when I click any button in the menu, all the commands are ran, I am wondering how to run only the clicked menu?

## MWE

**(Problem: whichever menu I click, it runs all the menu labels)**

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk,messagebox

def show_child_win(win,text=''):
    win_child = tk.Toplevel(win)

    var_l1 = tk.StringVar()
    l1 = tk.Label(win_child,textvariable=var_l1)
    l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    var_l1.set(text)
    win_child.after(3*1000,lambda: win_child.destroy())

win = tk.Tk()
menubar = tk.Menu(win)

menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Scripts", menu=menu)

dict_label_func = {
    'function_01': lambda win: show_child_win(win,text='function_01'),
    'function_02': lambda win: show_child_win(win,text='function_02'),
    'last_function': lambda win: show_child_win(win,text='last_function')
}

for label, func in dict_label_func.items():
    menu.add_command(label=label,command = lambda x=win: func(x))

win.config(menu=menubar)
win.mainloop()
```

## How to make the code run only the function it supposed to do?

Comment: Change your menu command to `command = lambda f=func: f(win)` (you don't need the `x = win` but it still works if you include it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments of @Henry, The following code works good:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk,messagebox

def show_child_win(win,text=''):
    win_child = tk.Toplevel(win)

    var_l1 = tk.StringVar()
    l1 = tk.Label(win_child,textvariable=var_l1)
    l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    var_l1.set(text)
    win_child.after(3*1000,lambda: win_child.destroy())

win = tk.Tk()
menubar = tk.Menu(win)

menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Scripts", menu=menu)

dict_label_func = {
    'function_01': lambda win: show_child_win(win,text='function_01'),
    'function_02': lambda win: show_child_win(win,text='function_02'),
    'last_function': lambda win: show_child_win(win,text='last_function')
}

for label, func in dict_label_func.items():
    menu.add_command(label=label,command = lambda f=func: f(win))

win.config(menu=menubar)
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in your `lambda` functions, I think you are not able to understand the difference between `func` and `func()`.

`abcd` basically represents a function which can be called.

`abcd()` is actually calling that `abcd` function.

`lambda` behaves like `abcd`, so do not need to do `abcd: abcd()`.

Here is the corrected part of the code:

```
dict_label_func = {
    'function_01': lambda: show_child_win(win, text='function_01'),
    'function_02': lambda: show_child_win(win, text='function_02'),
    'last_function': lambda: show_child_win(win, text='last_function')
}

for label, func in dict_label_func.items():
    menu.add_command(label=label,command = func)
```

Please refer this tutorial on [functions](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/function) and [lambda](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/anonymous-function).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the trouble with only the last function version running for all three menu entries is the mechanism behind the  assignment of mutable values in Python where instead of assigning the actual current value behind a mutable object the variable holds the object itself which value may change what causes then unexpected side-effects.

It is a common source of confusion not only for a beginner when after a loop different objects with assigned different values at each iteration have after the loop exit all the same value which was assigned to the last one in the last loop iteration (in your case all of the three 'different' functions are just the third function assigned in the last loop iteration).

The best path to success in programming is to get such kind of problems out of the way with a clean and simple design of code structure. Usage of loops for three iterations and lambdas where it is not necessary makes the code only more complicated and harder to maintain.

Following this guide rule for a better code design results in explicit creation of different functions for handling different menu entries. This way there is no loop, no lambda and no trouble with getting it all the right way. The nice side-effect here is that the code becomes better readable and maintainable as you can easily see from code which function handles which event without the need of looking what loops do or which items are actually stored in dictionaries or reason about what a lambda function will actually do.

The code below eliminates the loops and lambdas and therefore doesn't need a dictionary. I suggest to build further programming upon this kind of code design instead of looking for fixing an unnecessary complicated one:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk,messagebox

def show_child_win(win,text=''):
    win_child = tk.Toplevel(win)

    var_l1 = tk.StringVar()
    l1 = tk.Label(win_child,textvariable=var_l1)
    l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    var_l1.set(text)
    win_child.after(3*1000,lambda: win_child.destroy())

win = tk.Tk() 
#   ^ -- create window and use it as default
#      parameter value --v
def show_child_win_1(win=win,text='function_01'):
    show_child_win(win,text)
def show_child_win_2(win=win,text='function_02'):
    show_child_win(win,text)
def show_child_win_l(win=win,text='last_function'):
    show_child_win(win,text)
# ^-- create different functions handling different menu entries

menubar = tk.Menu(win)

menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Scripts", menu=menu)

menu.add_command(label='function_01'  ,command = show_child_win_1)
menu.add_command(label='function_02'  ,command = show_child_win_2)
menu.add_command(label='last_function',command = show_child_win_l)

win.config(menu=menubar)
win.mainloop()
```